# GroovyShell Not Parsing Curly Braces of Placeholder in GStrings

Tags: java, parsing, groovy, compilation, groovyshell

I have been working with AST analysis and instrumentation of Groovy applications and I noticed that the curly braces in the Placeholders of the GStrings are totally left out after `Parsing` phase of Compilation.

For example,

```
log.debug "Found ${recentEvents?.size() ?: 0} events in the last $deltaSeconds seconds"
```

becomes

```
log.debug("Found $(recentEvents?.size()) ? recentEvents?.size() : 0 events in the last $deltaSeconds seconds")
```

As such, the statements inside the placeholder gets mixed up with the other parts of the string and cause error when compiled after instrumentation.

The `GroovyShell` class is set up like this:

```
STAnalysisAST stal = new STAnalysisAST()
CompilerConfiguration cc = new CompilerConfiguration(CompilerConfiguration.DEFAULT)
cc.addCompilationCustomizers(stal) 
GroovyShell gshell = new GroovyShell(cc)
```

This is an excerpt of the `STAnalysisAST` Class:

```
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
public class STAnalysisAST extends CompilationCustomizer{

    public STAnalysisAST(Logger logger){
        super(CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
        nodes = new ArrayList<ICFGNode>()
    }

    @Override
    void call(SourceUnit source, GeneratorContext context, ClassNode classNode) {
        def _code = Helper.getSourceFromNode(classNode)
    }
}
```

where `_code` would show that the curly braces of the placeholders are already missing the time the Semantic Analysis begins.

This is the excerpt from `Helper` class where `getSourceFromNode` is defined:

```
class Helper {
    public static String getSourceFromNode(ClassNode classNode){
        java.io.StringWriter writer = new java.io.StringWriter();
        AstNodeToScriptVisitor visitor = new AstNodeToScriptVisitor(writer);
        visitor.visitClass(classNode);
        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

`AstNodeToScriptVisitor` class comes with Groovy 2.4.6.

Please help a brother out.